# What is the default charset for apache log files?

Tags: apache-2.2

What's the default character encoding for Apache's log files?  There's no mention of encoding at all on http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_log_config.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not default charset, Apache's own messages are logged in the current locale, so the charset of that locale is used. Anything you print to stderr is logged verbatim, byte for byte, so the charset you use in those messages is used.